# How to load DyGraphs using require.js

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I am trying to integrate DyGraph in a web site that uses require.js for loading modules.
It is possible to load DyGraph using require? 
I looked at the code and did not see any define() in there.

I came across this project where it looks like it needs to be "wrapped".

https://github.com/mgmarino/kanso-dygraphs

Has anyone done this before?

Thanks.

Comment: Feel free to file a feature request: https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/issues/new

Answer (score 0):

The latest dygraphs was fine to load with just:

```
// put this in your require config
paths: {
    'dygraphs'              : 'bower_modules/dygraphs/dygraph-combined',
}

...
require('dygraphs');

console.log(Dygraph); // Dygraph is added to global scope
```